# Добавить в запрос дополнительные данные

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос:

```
INSERT INTO orders (`date`, `dostavka_id`)
VALUES (NOW(), $dostavka_id)
```

В самой таблице `orders`, кроме `date` и `dostavka_id`, есть ещё `type`.
Есть таблица `info` с тем же `type`.
Собственно вопрос, как мне из таблицы `info`, вытащить `type` и записать его в `orders`?

Пробовал так:

```
INSERT INTO orders (`date`, `dostavka_id`)
VALUES (NOW(), $dostavka_id) LEFT JOIN info ON (info.type = orders.type)
```

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Вам надо вставить три поля `date`, `dostavka_id` и `type` так, чтобы `type` бралось из `info`, а остальные поля задавались напрямую? Тогда можно попробовать как-то так: `INSERT INTO orders (\`date\`, \`dostavka_id\`, \`type\`) SELECT NOW(), $dostavka_id, \`type\`  FROM \`orders\``

Comment: у меня есть две одинаковых ячейки(type) в двух разных базах. Мне нужно при вставке INSERT INTO VALUES, добавить ещё type из другой базы, по одинаковым айди :)

Comment: Ничегонепонимаю (c). Как и куда вы этот `type` вставить хотите? "Как из таблицы info вытащить type и записать его в orders" я показал (`INSERT INTO .. SELECT \`type\` FROM...`) Но раз это не то, то хотя бы пример можете привести? Т.е. что есть на входе, что должно получиться на выходе.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO orders (`date`, `dostavka_id`, `type`)
VALUES (NOW(), $dostavka_id, (SELECT `type` FROM orders where --тут вставьте условие, с помощью которого выбирается нужный type из orders--));
```